# How can I assign a Fit result to a function?

Tags: functions

I have this code

```
ntcrr[t_] := E^(a + b/t + c/t^2 + d/t^3)
kelvin[t_] := t + 273.15
a = -13.40956889; b = 4481.798865; c = -150521.6916; d = 1877102.652;
p1 = {30, ntcrr[kelvin[30]]}; p2 = {35, ntcrr[kelvin[35]]};
line := Fit[{p1, p2}, {1, x}, x]
```

{ 1.67709 - 0.0285019 x }

Then I plug in this function in my `Plot`

```
Plot[ntcrr[kelvin[t]]/(1.67709 - 0.0285019 t), {t, 30, 35}]
```

and that works, but I'd rather like to assign the `Fit` result to a function, like this:

```
line[x_] := Fit[{p1, p2}, {1, x}, x]
Plot[ntcrr[kelvin[t]]/line[t], {t, 30, 35}]
```

but that doesn't work. How can I assign a `Fit` result to a function?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `Set[]` (`=`) instead of `SetDelayed[]` (`:=`) on the output of `Fit[]`, like so:

```
line[x_] = Fit[{p1, p2}, {1, x}, x];

Plot[ntcrr[kelvin[t]]/line[t], {t, 30, 35}]
```

---

**Addendum by Mr. Wizard**

You may wish to localize the variable in this construct, so that the creation of the definition is safe from a global assignment.  Here are two ways of achieving this:

- `Block`

  ```
  Block[{x},
        f[x_] = Fit[{p1, p2}, {1, x}, x]
        ]
  ```
- [Formal Symbols](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/LettersAndLetterLikeForms.html#173509264) (looks better in a notebook):

  ```
  f[\[FormalX]_] = Fit[{p1, p2}, {1, \[FormalX]}, \[FormalX]]
  ```

Comment: That was almost *too* easy, I don't think I should upvote you for this ;-). Thanks a bunch! (I did upvote, of course)

Comment: No problem; though I should also probably tell you about `FindFit[]`, which returns the parameters only instead of the function itself. It might be more convenient for you to use...

Comment: Do you think so? I'm not really interested in the separate coefficients, just the function. With `FindFit` I would have to reconstruct the function myself, right?

Comment: Well, I said "might be"; you could, for instance, do `{m, k} = {m0, k0} /. FindFit[{p1, p2}, m0 x + k0, {m0, k0}, x]` and then `Plot[ntcrr[kelvin[t]]/(m t + k), {t, 30, 35}]`.

Comment: Thanks for the addendum, Wizard. :)

Answer (score 3):

If, for any conceivable reason, you want to preserve the `SetDelayed (:=)`, you might want to try

```
line2 := Function[{y}, Evaluate[Fit[{p1, p2}, {1, y}, y]]]
Plot[ntcrr[kelvin[t]]/line2[t], {t, 30, 35}, Evaluated -> True]
```

Comment: Now, try executing `line2[0]`.

Comment: @J.M. Touché. Adding `Evaluate` should have fixed the issue, though one may wonder if there is any point in keeping the `SetDelayed` at this point. Not a very good answer, I reckon.

Comment: @stevenvh On my computer (Mathematica v 8.0.1 on Win7) the code I suggested works just fine, even though J.M.'s solution is superior beyond a shadow of a doubt.

Comment: @AndreaColonna: if you wonder about `SetDelayed`, why don't you just exchange it to `Set` (`=`). That works alright and is the thing to do here. With that change, I think it is a perfect way to define such a function, to some extent I like that even better than the function definition per downvalues. You should also note that the `Evaluated -> True` option isn't actually necessary then.

Comment: @AndreaColonna: one more point: you can/should use the same techniques to localize or protect the symbols used as function arguments as in J.M.s answer, e.g.: `line2=Block[{y},Function[{y}, Evaluate[Fit[{p1, p2}, {1, y}, y]]]]`